# CORS issue performing api calls in react/redux application

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, reactjs, redux

I was trying to implement a [mailchimp api](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/) and came across a cross domain issue with an error in chrome like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/members.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 501.

After some research it turns out that api calls I make are made from the browser (I simply call api from one of my actions), but to fix this issue they need to be made on the server.

Hence I am trying to figure out a way to call an api from the server inside of my action, to bypass this issue.

**EDIT:**
One of the solutions I found is to use jsonp for this, however I had to drop it as well, as I can't authenticate with it.

Comment: There are [quite a few](https://npms.io/search?term=mailchimp) Node packages to interact with Mailchimp.

Comment: You can use [`node-http-proxy`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) to proxy the MailChimp API.

Comment: @Steven this looks like a neat solution, I tried going through their docs, but still don't understand how exactly it should be set up, could you provide an example as an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to proxy api calls through express in the following way:

**In your express config:**

```
import request from 'request'

app.use('/api', function (req, res) {
  let url = 'your_api_url' + req.url
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res)
})
```

What this allows you to do is instead of calling `https://myapi.com/endpoint` in your components is to use `/api/endpoint` this way express will replace all instances of `/api` on your server with your api url and perform an api call from the server itself.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem calling google places api. How would I call this from my React action. Right now I have something like this.  let url = `${GOOGLE_URL}/textsearch/json?query=${location}&pagetoken=${nextPageToken}&radius=500&key=${GOOGLE_KEY}` how would I use the above express api in my call.